# Owl Carousel Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm a developing own Wordpress theme. I'm using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

But getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` from 1st line and doesn't show any carousel item. Sorry my bad english.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel();

});
```

Comment: Could you provide you're entire code (or a link). You probably dont't have $ corectly defined. Do you have jQuery included?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't include jQuery. Thank you.

Comment: Change `$(document).ready(function() {` to `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. WordPress includes jQuery by default, in no-conflict mode.

Comment: @rnevius Changed. Working thanks. ^^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery is included with WordPress by default [in no-conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). In `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available, so you need to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Comment: I am still getting same error after above change. What should I need to add more?

Comment: @LaxmiSalunkhe , comments are not the place for new questions. Please post a new question, if you're still experiencing this issue.